# Show hide text box when specific option is selected from dropdown inside dynamic form Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have a form where a user could **add** `one/more` div of **Address** on `click` of add **button**.

I want if user **select** `options=5` from the dropdown, want to show and hide textbox in that particular address Div.

**Component Code**

```
        get contactFormGroup() {
            return this.form.get('Array') as FormArray;
          }

          ngOnInit() {
            this.form= this.fb.group({
              Array: this.fb.array([])
            });
          }

          createContact(): FormGroup {
            return this.fb.group({
              ABC: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
              Test: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
            });
          }

          addContact() {
            this.Group.push(this.createContact());
          }

          showValue(event) {
            const selectedValue = event;
            if (selectedValue === '5') {
                this.showValuetxtbox = true;
            } else {
                this.showValuetxtbox = false;
            }
          }
```

Comment: will you be able to add a screenshot of your developed component?

Comment: Added screnshot... if i select ROM = 'other' in dropdown it will populate one value textbox..but in my case i selected ROM = 'other' in first address div but value textbox populated in both addresses..not in the specific one..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looping to add the divs, you could use a template reference variable on the drop down. e.g #select then refer to that in the *ngIf:

```
    <form [formGroup]="addExpressionform">
        <div formArrayName="expressionArray">
            <div *ngFor="let item of contactFormGroup.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">

              <carbon-dropdown #select
                                (optionSelected)="showValue($event)"
                                [formControlN]="'UOM'"
                                [options]="listOptions" [formGroup]="item"
                                name="UOM" 
                                >
                            </carbon-dropdown>

                            <carbon-text-input *ngIf="select.value == 5" 
                                [formControlN]="'Value'"
                                [formGroup]="item"
                                name="Value"
                                >
                            </carbon-text-input>
                    <carbon-button type="primary" (click)="submit()" id="save-parameter">Save</carbon-button>

            </div>                  
        </div>
    </form>
```

[Simplified StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oueogo).

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this Stackblitz,](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qyvlxjqxdep) it's referred to in the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) and could serve as boilerplate to what you are trying to achieve.

You should isolate every possible type of question by creating a different `class` for each one, so you can shape the data and then use `ngSwitch` to dynamically create the HTML accordingly.

Question base class:

```
export class QuestionBase<T> {
  controlType: string;
  value: T;
  key: string;
  label: string;
  // etc

  constructor(options) {
    // constructor logic
  }
}
```

Some special class that inherents from base class

```
import { QuestionBase } from './question-base';

export class SpecialQuestion extends QuestionBase<string> {
  controlType = 'specialQuestion';
  type: string;

  // special Question
  specialValue: string;


  constructor(options) {
    super(options);
    this.type = options['type'] || '';
  }
}
```

Then, a question component:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <label>{{question.label}}</label>        
  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">
    // controls logic
    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" >        
    <select *ngSwitchCase="'specialQuestion'"></select>
  </div>          
</div>
```

Then you throw this into a container component where you loop through the entire questions array.

This way your code will be future proof and reusable as you add/change functionality to your forms down the road. You won't have to create spaghetti to meet edge case requirements like an extra input field.